# How to replace onClick event dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

I have following page:

```
<body>

<a href="#" id=key onclick="func(0)">foo</a>

</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function func(k){
    alert(k);
    $('#key').click(function() {func(++k)});
}   
</script>
```

My expectations of this code execution following:

I click on link and see 0, then click one more time and see 1, then click one more time and see 2....then 3....4...5....6

But actual result:

I click on link and see 0,
I click on link and see 0 and then 1 twice,
I click on link one more time and see 0 2 2 2 2 and 1.

Please help to understand what does happen and and how to rewrite it?

### Update

Key of the question is invocation of old function with new argument on `onclick` action!

Comment: I wonder how the `<script>` tag outside </html>` is working for you...

Comment: but it is working for my chrome)

Comment: May I know why you want to *"replace onClick event dynamically"* for doing what you've explained in the description..? The answer for your title is just `$("#key").removeAttr('onclick');`, but it doesn't do what you've described in the body. Could you please [edit] the question and elaborate so that the questions title and description match..?

Comment: The update even invalidates your own answer. *invocation of old function with new argument on onclick action"* - Your answer completely destroys the *old function*...

Comment: and bind old function new argument!

Comment: You have possibility to edit my question if you want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote function like this:

```
function func(k){
    alert(k);
    $("#key").removeAttr('onclick');
    $("#key").unbind('click')   
    $('#key').click(function() {func(++k)});
}
```

and I see expected result

Comment: This is a very inefficient way to do it... every time you're removing the existing handler and adding a new one...

Comment: Yea i was just saying this is very strange and inefficient way to do the counting thing you explained in question, in case if anyone comes across this in future.

Comment: it is not necessary counting - it maybe absolutely different functions

Comment: Whatever it is, you are unbinding an event handler, removing it and re-binding it inside an event handler... this is really inefficient.. If you want to avoid global variables, look into closures. I'm pretty sure this isn't the right way of doing whatever it is.

Answer (score 4):

you can set a global variable and increase in each function call

```
var globalCounter = 0;

$('#key').click(function() {
    alert(globalCounter);
    globalCounter++;
});
```

you dont need

```
onclick="func(0)"
```

in html tag because you already set click event handler with

```
$('#key').click(function(){});
```

Comment: Actually I cannot delete inline onclick. This example is very simplified.

Comment: What you mean with "cannot delete inline onclick". If you can't access the HTML, you can use JS: `this.onclick = null;` (in `func`). The click handler attached like Alper has suggested will still work.

Comment: this html is product of jsp. I cannot change jsp logic

Comment: **<a href="#" id=key onclick="func(0)">foo</a>** should be same

Comment: @gstackoverflow You can simply use the `onlick` handler itself for doing what you mentioned like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26449796/2333214)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply modify your function as follows:

```js
function func() {
  if (!window.count)
    window.count = 0;
  alert(count++);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="key" onclick="func()">foo</a>
```

Side notes:

- You should add the `<script>` block inside your `<html>` document, preferably just before closing `<body>`
- You are missing quotes around the `id` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the inline click handler is setting `k` to 0 and adding a new jQuery click listener on every click. Each jQuery handler will increase the value of `k` on every click, and this creates a mess you can see in the alerted values.

At first, remove the inline `onclick` from `#key`. You can do it without breaking anything, just set it to `null` within `$(document).ready()`:

```
$('#key').prop('onclick', null);
```

Then for the click counter, create a variable and a new click handler:

```
var clickCounter = 0;
$('#key').click(function () {
    clickCounter += 1;
});
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psv6muqn/).

Answer (score -1):

You are adding a new `func` on each click. That is why you are seeing the new number many times, as well as the old ones.

Add these lines to remove previous handlers:

```
$("a").prop("onclick", null); //remove default "onclick" handler - otherwise the 0 will always continue coming
$("#key").off("click"); //remove old jQuery assigned handlers
```

Then send `++k` to new handler.

Comment: you're confusing the ++k and k++. ++k is inc and then send not otherwise

Comment: after this advise I see only 0 alert

Comment: @JNF but it doen't matter.

Comment: try to execute. it returns 0 always.

Comment: That's because of the `onclick` embedded, try now.